# Would Marx consider salary workers to be members of the proleteriat?

Tags: socialism, marxism

I am struggling to map the concepts of "proletariat" and "bourgeoisie" to modern life. They appear to be equivalent to "lower class" and "middle class", but today those terms are really used to distinguish "blue collar" and "white collar" jobs, and map onto family income.

My hunch is that anyone working for a full-time salary, a short-term contract or zero-hour contract is "proletariat", even if it's a really nice job. Especially since the business usually owns the product of your work (physical or intellectual). Only someone who *owns* a business, earns *dividends* and *hires others to do work* is bourgeoisie.

I'm not sure if self-employed consultants and investors fit neatly into these buckets. And there aren't many landed gentry left in the world. So I appreciate Marx might not map neatly onto all modern roles.

Am I correct to that a salaried, white-collar desk worker with a full-time contract (and no stock options) would fit the Marxist conception of "proletariat" even though we wouldn't call them "working class" today?

Comment: That's going to depend on which modern Marxist theorist you ask. Marx himself conceived the idea of a rentier capitalist, who could earn money from rent and financial interest. It should be evident that an employee making hundreds of thousands of dollars or more per year can readily acquire the real property or financial capital necessary to live off such an income in short order. He also talked about "functional capitalists" who organized the means of production. Which jobs involve organization of the means of production? I am sure that different Marxists would have different ideas.

Comment: To extend @Obie2.0's point, a modern question is whether labor is **productive**. Some theorists ask not just whether one must labor in order to live, but whether one's labor is helpful to society at large. (This was in response to [guaranteed jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_guarantee) among other developments last century.)

Comment: The more time that passes, the less sense Marx makes.

Comment: @blud The more our economic, cultural and social conditions change the less sense Marx make and he'd probably be fine with that. If we continued to do the same for longer he would still be relevant.

Comment: @haxor789 however, they have not changed all that much in ways Marx didn't predict - just a few patches around the edges.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In [Marxist Class theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marxian_class_theory):

> The first criterion divides a society into the owners and non-owners
> of means of production. In capitalism, these are capitalist
> (bourgeoisie) and proletariat. Finer divisions can be made, however:
> the most important subgroup in capitalism being petite bourgeoisie
> (small bourgeoisie), people who possess their own means of production
> but utilize it primarily by working on it themselves rather than
> hiring others to work on it. They include self-employed artisans,
> small shopkeepers, and many professionals. Jon Elster has found
> mention in Marx of 15 classes from various historical periods.

People who receive most of their income from property ownership rather than labor are the *bourgeoisie*, and for the most part, salaried workers would not fit in this category.

They would also not be part of the *petite bourgeoisie* for the most part, because they don't own their own means of production even though they don't hire others to work for them. The *petite bourgeoisie* in modern society would be people like taxi cab owner-operators, many truckers, most family farmers, and many skilled tradesmen like plumbers.

Upper middle class professional and managerial salaried office workers who have not yet acquire significant income producing property of their own (as opposed to those who are self-employed or have gained, for example, wealth from stock options in the companies where they work) are still members of the proletariat in a Marxist analysis.

From the same link, in the Marxist analysis:

> Class is thus determined by property relations, not by income or
> status.

One would have to make a leap that Marx himself did not, to see human capital as a form of capital (contrary to the fundamental divide Marxism creates between labor and property based income), in which case one could see them as members of the *petite bourgeoisie*.

They are similarly not members of the *[Lumpenproletariat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpenproletariat)* made up of people such as criminals, vagabonds, and prostitutes.

Marx largely predated the historical period in which the "upper middle class" emerged and gained economic importance.

Union-management relations law, in contrast, largely puts the upper middle class among the members and allies of "management" who are therefore forbidden from unionizing.

On the other hand, one could legitimately look at the migration of managerial and professional class salaried employees with college educations to the Democratic party in the U.S., and of self-employment working class and middle class farmers and small business owners to the Republican party in the U.S., as a validation of Marxist class theory. Also, notably, many such people including civil servants, teachers, professors, and graduate students, are unionized.

> I'm not sure if self-employed consultants and investors fit neatly
> into these buckets.

Investors, even if they don't make huge money from doing so, are clearly members of the *bourgeoisie* in a Marxist analysis. Self-employed consultants would generally be members of the proletariat except to the extent that the consulting was capital intensive, in which case they might be members of the *petite bourgeoisie*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142237/discussion-on-answer-by-ohwilleke-would-marx-consider-salary-workers-to-be-membe).

Comment: Try not to conflate the capitalist with the bourgeoisie (which is more of a social capitalist), of which the self employed is (the former and not the latter) in that Marx would consider the proletariat an entrepreneur with copyright, reasonable margins, and exclusionary plausible use. A social capitalist bourgeoisie would use a W2, a petite bourgeoisie would have trade secrets, and a proletariat will use neither if they can help it. Earning labor by wage instead of a scope of work doesn't make one a proletariat, earning by deflationary corpus does. Once again the proletariat discredits itself.

Answer (score 9):

These terms are **not used** to "*to distinguish "blue collar" and "white collar" jobs, and map onto family income.*" as you write.

If I have a burger stand, working there myself but also hire a single helper part time to peel me potatos, I am a bourgeoisie in terms of Marxism, worth sending to Siberia right now in terms of Stalinism. If I work at Microsoft and fly to space for holidays like [Charles Simonyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Simonyi), I am "intelligentsia" at worst, but this was not considered a real class, so my true class would likely be proletariat anyway.

While proletariat is mostly seen as poor, and bourgeoisie as rich, it does not actually matter how rich I am. It only matters what kind of work relations do I have. If I own the means of production and hire workers to work on these means, I am bourgeoisie. If I own the land and hire workers to work on it, I am a "kulak" (wealthy peasant), and [also an ideal candidate for Siberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekulakization). If I only work on my land I am a peasant. If I own a forge and only work there myself as a smith, also likely okay as long as I hand my forge to the [Kolchoz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolkhoz) (collective farm) immediately. However, any hired worker in my forge would change my status into "petty bourgeois".

Marxism does put separately a "worker aristocrat" group that get high qualified, well paid jobs, where Charles Simonyi likely belongs. True Marxist would say that these belong to minority and have no much impact on anything. Bourgeoisies create this social category artificially, to split the working class and create there confusion. They - U! - will never succeed!

Being from the former Soviet Union, I have learned these things in depth and width at the university, even if my specialty had nothing to do with them. It could be other (maybe better) explanations on how does the society work, but as much as Marxism is considered, here you are.

Comment: why do you bring up Stalinism?

Comment: Repressions have been applied as "per class", hence classifying into classes was between the core concepts of Stalinism. The classification was Marxism based, or at least that the PR wrote. Here want to say, many actually quite poor and hard working people where classified as bourgeois, and not at random but strictly by criteria.

Comment: The question doesn't talk about Stalinism.

Comment: @user253751 Seems to me implementations of country-level Communism have often veered towards Stalin-level coercion.  So the insistence that Stalin has no place in this answer is all yours.  Besides, Stalin was mentioned in terms of the *penalties* possible - which are enlightening - while the answer is very clear that the *classification* is basic Marxism.

Comment: @user253751 I'd say that Stalin as a person isn't important here. Think about it only as a metaphor for _any_ agent that wants to impose such a woefully inadequate economical classification upon a society.

Comment: *"If I own a forge and only work there myself as a smith, also likely okay as long as I hand my forge to Kolchoz immediately. However, any hired worker in my forge would change my status into "petty bourgeois"."* - no,that's incorrect. The smith would be considered *petite bourgeoisie* because he owns his own means of production but doesn't use them to exploit anyone. Hiring a helper would turn them into actual *bourgeoisie*, because they now gain capital by exploiting a worker through owning their means of production.

Comment: @Gábor what do you mean by "impose a classification"? Reality exists outside of any taxonomy and does not have a preferred one. People *are* proletariat or bourgeois, left or right, and tall or short no matter whether you like it or not. Nobody "imposes" that people are tall or short - they just are.

Comment: A peasant also owns the means of production, the land. Joining Kolchoz is the must but otherwise this is okay. Joining Kolchoz is the must is because otherwise like Lenin wrote such small producers "produce Capitalism, always, spontaneously and massively"

Comment: @Stančikas No a peasant did not own the means of production, the land. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasant They apparently were either slaves, serfs or free peasants, but each of them still had a landlord who actually owned the means of production and extracted profit through taxation because of that ownership title. And the communists were hardly the first to extract surplus at the maximum of what peasants were able to give, there are lots of such examples and peasant revolts and wars when they got near or beyond the breaking point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_peasant_revolts

Comment: The question I would ask about bringing in Stalin is, "how does this improve the explanation?" I'm not seeing here how it does. (Though I do fully understand having an intense dislike of Stalin, and how this might affect your opinions on things that Stalin ostensibly promoted.)

Comment: @Stančikas The problem is that while Lenin/Stalin base their classification on Marx, they nevertheless apply them differently and in very different circumstances. Like for Marx that was a more or less neutral description of the material conditions that people are in. So people in the role of the capitalist/worker just act in their best interest given the circumstances. No necessity to assume individual malice. The idea being that if you change the conditions you change how they act. So Marx argued that people in these similar economic relations should cooperate to overcome them.

Comment: @Stančikas So Marx was pre-revolution arguing that there is an overwhelming majority with shared conditions that should get aware of that and utilize it. While Lenin/Stalin were post-revolution. And there this classification makes a whole lot less sense. If they had a majority revolution in an industrialized country as Marx predicted, they'd "simply" change the material conditions and these categories would be obsolete. But as they weren't, they relied on capitalist, became capitalists themselves while still pretending to vigorously hate capitalists as "the enemy".

Comment: @user253751 Conditionally, if you are a Marxist and accept the categorization. I'm not, thus I don't accept that these categories exist independently from our opinion, on the contrary, I posit that these categories are imposed upon us by this school of thought called Marxism. I don't classify people like that and I can see absolutely no reason to do so. And this more of a general observation: the mere fact that some thinker invented a way to classify people or any other phenomena doesn't imply that such a classification is valid, meaningful or advantageous.

Comment: @Gábor With all due respect but the question was not about whether the classification is valid, meaningful or advantageous and certainly not whether you agree with it. The question was where Marx would classify group X or wider where Marxists would do so. Stančikas added where Marxist-Leninists (Stalinism) HAVE classified these people and mentioning the penalizing could be seen as giving a description of how he knows that or being his revenge on the system by mention that as often as possible. In other words he at least has an argument here, you don't, do you?

Comment: @haxor789 Yes, the question was different. That's why we're not adding answers but are discussing some related ideas in comments. I just added a possible point of view that would allow names, like Stalin's, to be mentioned.

Comment: @haxor789 As you can see, I only brought up my own opinion because user253751 replied by calling this categorization independent of any human categorization attempt, simply stating that people do belong to these whether we agree or not. This was what I had denied, nothing else, saying that using these categories is dependent on accepting this categorization in the first place.

Comment: @haxor789 But, if we want to turn back to the original question, yes, the fact that some feel the need to discuss how those people would be categorized, and the fact that there are conflicting answers, might very well be construed as an argument to show that the proletariat/bourgeois categorization was inherently inadequate or erroneous from its inception (not in the sense that they don't exist but that the division is so exhaustive, mechanical and deterministic as Marx imagined). That's my argument for you. :-)

Comment: @Gábor But user253751 is correct. First and foremost these categorizations were descriptive. Like one group worked for money the other obtained money from owning capital and letting other's work. That's what makes Stalin in this question kinda controversial because their categorization was no longer descriptive. Like for Marx a capitalist without capital is not a capitalist, but apparently for Stalin it's more about identity than description.

Comment: @haxor789 That's your opinion, mine is that he wasn't correct. Marx introduced an overly simplistic categorization, one that ignores a multitude of factors (as evidenced by this question) and drew false conclusions from this false categorization. Conclusions that you probably accept but others, who don't share the same conviction, won't. And Stalin was mentioned just as one of the agents who had the position to impose these ideas upon a society. You and me, we're just free intellectuals who might advocate for one or the other. But he and the others like him had the power to do so in real life.

Comment: @Gábor Again a) that is majorly irrelevant to the question and totally off topic, b) Marx did that more than 100 years ago and you can argue that this made a lot more sense when the economy was largely dominated by the primary and the upcoming secondary sector which were largely productive while the modern service economy is largely unproductive. c) Again the point wasn't that a government imposes these categories the point was that the proletariat should unite, rise and overcome these material conditions.

Comment: @haxor789 Then we will go on not agreeing. OP complained that he had problems applying the Marxian categories to contemporary situations. I just happened to voice my opinion that this is primarily due to this categorization being wrong in the first place, and even more so today. Instead of trying to massage it to fit to our current situation, we might just as well recognize that it _is_ so inadequate that there is no need or way to adapt it. I don't think this is off topic as it directly addresses the problems of the OP. And the fact that you don't agree wouldn't make it so, either. :-)

Comment: @Gábor This isnt' even OPs question, it's an to it and while you can make a case for why it's not entirely OT to mention Stalin, you can't really make your point without going completely off topic. Also again it originally is about drawing a line somewhere, you can't really be "wrong" doing that, unless you self-contradict. You can be wrong in drawing conclusions from that or applying ideas to that, but that's a different story. Also you provide no explanation or evidence for your assertion.

Comment: @Gábor All categorizations are overly simplistic. All of them. 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it doesn't refer to income, but rather to the way in which people generate that income and the property relation concerning that. The proletariat does it through labor, the bourgeoisie through ownership of the means of production and letting other people work for them. That being said, if you'd look at these groups ones you've drawn the line though, you would still likely have had found similar results of economic outcome and social status.

However the actual poor, unemployed, unsteady employed, working poor, individual service workers and others who struggle to stay alive, he would have grouped outside of the two classes as "Lumpenproletariat" who he categorized as unreliable and lacking the class consciousness of the proletariat and which are thus detrimental to the workers revolution.

Also one thing to keep in mind is that when Marx was around the economy consisted largely of the primary (agriculture and raw material) and the secondary (industries and manufacturing products) economic sector. Making a shift from the primary towards the secondary sector. That is, he saw and predicted that the individual manufacturers and small producers of raw material will be pushed out of business by the industrial producers who can do it faster (due to machines), cheaper (due to a decreased amount of labor) and more reliable (due to machines). And so production of goods will move from unique and individual to collective and standardized. So you had this alienation from labor, previously people made a whole product from start to finish now they only produce one part of it and the product quite literally doesn't bear the name of the creator anymore, but the name of the company owner (brand).

And so he saw this productive wage labor (in the sense that they produce something), as the new dominating form of labor. The freelance producer was on it's way out and the service industry was likely not significant yet, so the focus was on the industrial worker.

And for that group owning the means of production or not, was quite significant. They could operate the means of production and produce the necessities of their society by themselves, in fact they already did that, but their socio-economic and political status was still that of an underclass. While the production is collective, the distribution of power, agency, capital, work and rewards in that collective is massively unequal.

So it's not entirely unreasonable to ask the question whether white collar workers were even fully included in that classification or whether they were just treated as an edge case. Like sure you could abstract the classification and speak about "petty bourgeoisie" and "worker aristocracy" as bourgeoisie and proletariat, but at some point this becomes quite questionable.

I mean the petit bourgeoisie was never meant to last or be significant according to Marx, who apparently firmly believed in the potential of the industrial revolution to wipe out all small producers. So either the petit bourgeoisie would become regular bourgeoisie or drop down to proletariat or lumpenproletariat. So they held out a lot longer than they were supposed to. Not to mention that the industrialized production and the standardization wasn't all as great as anticipated. Sometimes you need unique and specialized production and the more optimized the process is, the harder it is to "just change it". So a lot more companies survived in a niche than what was anticipated by Marx.

Likewise the "service sector" was probably largely insignificant at the time and is now the single largest and most heterogeneous economic sector. Which ranges from "Lumpenproletariat" to industrial wage workers who are not hired directly but just "on demand", to clerks, mind workers all the way up to the management and CEOs. Which span a huge group of people who are hardly in similar economic, social and political relations. So it takes a lot of mental gymnastics to argue that CEOs and upper management are in the same class as the person cleaning the toilets. Despite being wage workers rather than capital owners they themselves are responsible for hiring and firing people and take a share of the bounty of the exploitation of people below them in the food chain and if they wanted they could even use their capital to become an owner.
Or just in general how for many of these people the "means of production" become a lot more nebulous. Like for explicit service jobs and not masked "non-contract" employments the source of income is the existence of rich people who can afford that service. So preserving a well of upper class who spends money lavishly is what keeps many people in business. So if workers took over the means of production they'd be screwed. They are technically lumpenproletariat.

So the more people are pushed away from the primary and secondary sectors the more they are further alienated from labor and the source of their existence. In Western countries these things might even be totally moved to other countries. Like there are thriving countries who are purely service no agriculture not production at all.

So on the one hand it's the single largest sector, makes up the new mode of labor. On the other hand the description of proletariat doesn't really fit.

Though you could still argue that the abstraction sorta kinda could be applied as people in employment still have a different perspective in terms of agency over their own work, which would differentiate the truly petit bourgeoisie from the "pseudo-self-employed" you know your uber driver or freelancer who basically works as an employee for just one company but because that employer wants to avoid social security and other benefits related to a contract they just hire them ondemand as a "self-employed entrepreneur" when in reality it's just a shady scheme to avoid paying people.

So you can argue that the owner/worker distinction still kinda sorta implies, but it's questionable as to whether you're still talking about the same thing that Marx referred to or whether we are already progressed further and thus are talking about different categories. I mean he himself argue that previous societies also had class relations. So just because you can make out a class relation doesn't mean you're talking about the same economic conditions.